# Rewrite few thousand URLs using nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I need to redirect few thousand URLs on my website. They all under `/Forum` path, so `/Forum/A` becomes `/Forum/new_path`, `/Forum/B` becomes `/Forum/another_new_path_of_B` etc. (those URLs can have query strings if that matters).

What is best way to do this? I need to have separate rule for each URL.

**Question #1**: Can I group rules in nginx? For example nginx, can check if URL starts with `/Forum/.*` and if it is - run rewrite rules (for better performance).

**Question #2**: Should I worry about performance impact of having few thousand redirects in my nginx configuration?

Comment: That depends. Can you make them fit a simple pattern, or are they arbitrary?

Comment: I would implement this in a separate script where you can use a database to store the from / to URLs. Furthermore, using query strings as source URLs makes it even more complicated in nginx, since nginx `rewrite` rule uses only URI as the rewrite base.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen wouldn't that slow things down by adding latency? Can you do that within Nginx config or do you somehow call a script from the Nginx config? A little more detail would be interesting. We have a production website with hundreds of rewrites, moderate traffic, performance seems fine.

Comment: It will add some latency, but saves implementation effort. I have done this by adding it as a PHP script. LUA might be used to perform a similar simplification, and it is a nginx module so it might be faster. I don't think latency matters that much with 301 redirects, since those are for legacy URLs most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite).

```
location /Forum {
  rewrite /Forum/([^/]*)(.*) /Forum/$1-new$2 break;
}
```

Comment: "new" suffix was just an example. I think I need to write separate rule for every URL. Your rule rewrites *all* paths within `/Forum/*` doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, all `/Forum/*` will rewrite. What do you want exactly? Is there any rule how to rewrite? If no, I think, you should write separate rules for every URL.